# How to Choose videos like photochooser task in window sphone8 programatically

Tags: windows-phone-8

Hi I want to pick a video programatically in windows phone 8 i'm using below snippet

```
var openPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wmv");
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");

var file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
```

but result is `NotSupportedException` over `Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker` wp8

Answer (score 1):

You can only use this `FileOpenFicker` on Windows 8/8.1 apps. Not on Windows Phone 8 apps even though the documentation says so. Take a look at [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/7e4492dc-d8f3-4dc5-8055-625352aaa8b6/fileopenpicker-class-on-wp8?forum=wpdevelop) Community Forum post

Comment: Please if you  have any sample code please post it for windows phone8